# CLOSED – html form not uploading

Tags: php, html

The data in the filled form are not uploaded to the database. If I remove the image column in the "insert into"-part then it works. So there's probably my error. There are no error messages.

```
elseif ($_GET["action"] == "save") {

     $imagepath = 'https://myurl.com/uploads/' . $_FILES['image']['name'];

     if (!empty($author) && !empty($title) && !empty($text)) {
        include_once("userdata.php");
        try {

          $db = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
          $query = $db->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO posts (author, title, text, date, image) VALUES(:author, :title, :text, NOW()), $imagepath)");
          $query->execute(array("author" => $author, "title" => $title, "text" => $text));
          $db = null;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added an extra bracket just after `NOW())`. Also you need to bind the `image` column as well. When you add the variable directly into `VALUES`, you have eliminated and broken the use of prepared statements. Hence the need to bind the variable

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (author, title, text, date, image) VALUES(:author, :title, :text, NOW(), :imagepath)");
$query->execute(array("author" => $author, "title" => $title, "text" => $text,"imagepath" => $imagepath));
```

Comment: My pleasure @MediumorchidCoder

Answer (score -1):

You are not using `$db->prepare()` correctly for the column image, and there is a extra bracket in the query. This is how you should do it, by creating a bind variable for the image:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (author, title, text, date, image) VALUES(:author, :title, :text, NOW(), :image)");
$query->execute(array("author" => $author, "title" => $title, "text" => $text, "image" => $imagepath));
```